# Openstego LSB Plugin

Tags: steganography

I ran the openstego command line below and got the error "No plugin found with name: lsb". I googled for this error and it said "abstract class should be added." I am not good at java but I want to know how to solve it.

```
root@~/openstego-0.6.1/lib# java -jar openstego.jar extract --algorithm=lsb -p realobama -sf barackobama2.png -xd /home/kst/Desktop/ 
No plugin found with name: lsb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip --algorithm parameter. Default algorithm is randomlsb. "lsb" is deprecated and not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should find out if you have the lsb algorithm available.  Run this command:

```
java -jar openstego.jar --algorithms
```

and see what algorithms you have installed. The name of the algorithms available will be shown, and they might be spelled different.  For example, I see RandomLSB as one of the algorithms it ships with, so I expect your command line should look more like this:

```
java -jar openstego.jar extract --algorithm=RandomLSB -p realobama -sf barackobama2.png -xd /home/kst/Desktop/
```